# I am attempting to 'able' a disabled button after a certain criteria has been met. Having trouble

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events, disabled-control

My HTML looks a like this for the specific button:

```
<h1 class = "counter">0</h1>

<button class="btn" type = "button" id = "lowerCountBtn" disabled>Lower Count</button>
```

In the Javascript, I have made a const variable used query selector to call the HTML element button. Counter was also made into a variable from a class on the HTML code.

My desire is for the disabled button to become an active button once the counter i have made following a tutorial, increase from 0. And when it returns to 0, the button in questions becomes disabled again.

The github link to the code is as follows:
https://github.com/Abdullah-Ijaz/Counter

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
const button = document.querySelector('button');


function ableButton(){ 
    if (counter.innerHTML === 0) {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
    else if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
        button.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

I see the function has been made but I assume I am just not calling the function somehow or the other. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I actually attempted that first since it made more sense to me but since the upper argument was comparing variables, I copied that idea below. So you say I can add an else if statement and call my buttons disabled as true of false below but within the above function blocks?
    function decrementCounter() {
    count --;
    counter.innerHTML = count;
    if (counter.innerHTML < '0') {
        counter.style.color = 'orange';
    }
    else if (counter.innerHTML === '0') {
        counter.style.color = 'white';
    }
if (count > '0') {
button.disabled = false;
}
}          
this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function inside of both your `incrementCounter` and `decrementCounter` functions after the rest of the logic.

Also, your conditions in those 2 functions are comparing strings against `'0'`.

Why not use the count variable and compare numbers `if (count > 0)` etc